# How to disable/mute left speaker in xfce4

Tags: sound, xubuntu, xfce

My left speakers give a crackling sound due to which I want to disable them. I am trying to mute the left speakers so that the crackling sound is muted. However, when I go to Volume Control/Sound settings on xfce and try to mute the volume of the left speaker, the right speaker is also getting muted. In fact, if I try reducing the percentage of volume in left, it is reflected in the right speaker as well.

How can I disable only the left speaker so that I can get rid of the crackling noise?

Please help.

Cheers
Viswa

Answer (score 0):

Did also "unlock" the volume controls, which should give you the possibility to manage both channels independently?

[image]